# Vanilla Javascript how override added function on event listener?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a bootstrap modal that has some custom events, like hidden.bs.modal, depending on where the user does, I want the function in this event to be replaced, maybe it's better to understand with a simple example, consider:

```js
const currentModal; // imagine an any modal here.

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   currentModal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', standardFunction );
});

function standardFunction(){
    alert('hi there');
   // this is standard output to modal closed
}

function buttonClickedChange(){
    // Here, i need override standardFunction

     this.standardFunction = function(){
         alert('modal event hidden.bs.modal changed with success!');
         // this must be override previous output
     };
}
```

What happens is that regardless of the redeclaration of the function, the output for the method is still standard, this is because the eventlistener does not refer to the stored function but only "copy" its content and creates its scope only inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is when you bind the event, you are referencing that function. When you replace it does not update the reference to that function. You can clearly see that this will not work with the example

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
function myFunc () {
  console.log(1);
}

btn.addEventListener("click", myFunc);

myFunc = function() {
  console.log(2);
}
```

```html
<button>Click Will Show 1</button>
```

Just remove the event listener and bind a new event.

```
currentModal.removeEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', standardFunction );
currentModal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', myUpdatedFunction );
```

```js
function myFunc () {
  console.log(1);
}


var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunc);


function myFunc2() {
  console.log(2);
}

btn.removeEventListener("click", myFunc);
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunc2);
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

If for some reason you can not remove the event, the only way around it would not to bind directly to the function, but to have another function call that function.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

var myFunc = function() {
  console.log(1);
}

function clickFunction () {
  myFunc();
}

btn.addEventListener("click", clickFunction);

myFunc = function() {
  console.log(2);
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Or how most people would do it is to add the logic into the function on what to do

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
var state = 0;

var myFunc = function() {
  if (state===0) {
    console.log(1);
  } else {
    console.log(2);
  }
}


state = 1;

btn.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: I'm going to do the most common, which is the switch, I just thought that the event listener made direct reference to the attribute passed and would change according to its change, but I understood that it is static after the parameter is passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You used function expressin instead of function declaration. When you use `function yourFunction` it is moved to the top with all of the other declared functions. When you use `var yourFunction = function ()` it is right there where you declared it. This means that `hidden.bs.modal` is searching for the top most function with that name which in this case is the first one you declared or the standard one. One of the ways is that you can declare your function in the global scope: `function standardFunctionOverride()` and add that to the listener.